Is there a a way to reorganize the rows in to charts?
Column C is categorical data. I want the age to be the column and the value at column D to be its value in each column. How to achieve this? I cannot do this manually as there are 5000 rows of data.

I did it manually. But this will take a whole week which is not feasible.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You need a Pivot Table.

In Excel, go to Insert > PivotTable > From Table/Range.
Select the full data range, including the header row, from columns A-D, and click OK.
In the PivotTable Fields pane, click and drag 'Year' to the Rows box, then 'Country/State' to Rows, 'Age...' to Columns and finally 'Fertility rate' to Values.

Done correctly, this will display something similar to this (which hopefully is what you want):

You can then grab the pivoted data from the cells or reference it directly.
